# WPF UserControl Click

Tags: wpf, user-controls, click

This is a related to [SO Question 3222456](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222456/click-event-in-usercontrol-wpf) ....

I'm creating my own UserControl with a few images and TextBlock's on it, nothing else.  I'd like to fire an event when the whole UserControl is clicked.  My problem (or misunderstanding) is that in WPF there only seem to be MouseUp events that I can hook into, no MouseClick.

So what's the best practice?  All the examples I can find act as if a mouseUp in WPF is equivalent to a click event but that's not right.  What if the user did a mouseDown in one part of the screen, held the mouse until it was over my control, and then released the mouse.  That's not a click of my control even though it fires a MouseUp event.

So how do I get a true MouseClick event for my UserControl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One very easy way would be to put your entire content into a button with an almost empty template and respond to the `Button`'s `OnClick` event.

This would look like

Old:

```
<UserControl ...>
  <Grid> ... </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

New:

```
<UserControl ...>
   <Button OnClick="YourEventHandler">
      <Grid> ... </Grid>
      <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="BlankButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
           <Border Background="#00000000">
             <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                               HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                               VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
           </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Button.Template>
   </Button>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thanks @Jens, this looks promising, I'll give that a try.  Do you use this technique frequently?  I see how it would work but it seems like a kludge.

Comment: I do use it quite frequently. You can create a ControlTemplate resource with the template in it and just use `<Button Template="{StaticResource BlankButtonTemplate}" />` then. This clears things up quite  a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use MouseDown?

Put the event in the User Control and simply do this:

```
 private void MyControl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
 {
     if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Clicked!");
     }
 }
```

Comment: Because neither MouseDown nor MouseUp, by themselves, constitute a MouseClick.  A MouseClick is a MouseDown event, followed by a MouseUp event within the same control.

Comment: Using the MouseUp event is a bit safer, because it allows the user to cancel the 'click' by moving the cursor outside of the control where the click was started.  But it has the risk of triggering a MouseUp event on a different control if it has one.